# Выборка за месяц силами mysql c учетом 29, 30 и 31 дня в месяце

Tags: php, mysql

Возможно, ли сделать выборку за месяц, используя **только** mysql или нужно подключить php?
Условие:
Берется число месяца.
Если число с **1**-го по **28**-е, то просто до такого же числа следующего месяца (т.к. все эти числа есть в следующем месяце).

Если берется **29**-е число, а в следующем нет **29**-го числа (только 28 дней), то до **28**-го включительно.

Если берется **30**-е число, а в следующем нет **30**-го числа (только 29 или 28 дней), то до **29**-го или **28**-го.

Для **31**-го аналогично, если нет ни 31, ни 30, ни 29 в следующем месяце, то до 30 или 29 или 28 включительно (смотря сколько будет).
Это в какой-то степени расчетный период, который используют операторы сотовой связи.

Comment: 29-ое число есть не в любом месяце. Часто в феврале только 28 дней. ))

Comment: А по существу, не надо городить огород. Достаточно будет и такого запроса: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_created BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE();`

Comment: вы бы расписали, как связан текущий месяц со следующим в вашей выборке.

Comment: Проще сделать, что выборка всегда за 30 дней и не надо париться со всеми этими 31 29 28 и пр

Comment: @Quazimorda знал про такой запрос, но поленился проверить сразу опытным путем, что INTERVAL 1 MONTH учитывает разницу в днях месяца. Верилось, что не учитывает). Спасибо за пинок. Напишите ответ. Отмечу как решение, если нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На практике хватает запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_created BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Конечно, разные длины месяцев будут при этом учтены. А вообще, поиск рулит. Может что-то вам будет полезно и в [этой теме](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.94f2ab9e-64c89f12-42cc8934-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month).